# Can't get localized strings from xml files correctly

Tags: java, android, string, localization

I've been racking my head with this...

I've got a localized strings.xml file in a values-en folder with this example string:
@string/my_string

The string has the following text stored in English: "My String"

When accessing the localized string via a layout, it works fine.

When I try to change it in code, that's where I get problems.

I store the string into an array of strings for later use.  The 'context' is passed from my activity to a data class and used with this line of code:

dataStrings = new String[] { (String) context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string) };

Later, I try to display this string, like so:

buttons[0].setText(dataStrings[0]);

It displays:

@string/my_string

How do I get it to display the string without '@string/', the proper localized string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run [`getString()` directly on the `Context` object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)); you don't need to run `getResources()`.  However, this should do the same thing as you're currently doing so I don't think that's the source of your problem.

The first thing to confirm is that what you think is happening is happening.  Either use the debugger to check that `buttons[0]` contains `"@string/my_string"` or try calling `setText()` with a hard-coded value to make sure the text is actually being updated on the correct button - e.g. `buttons[0].setText("StackOverflow!");`

Comment: Thanks Dave!

After checking the string contents, I've noticed that I'm using an incorrect array index (the array was much larger than the example posted).

Also, thanks for the heads up on the context object.  Is there any way to call it statically, without having to pass in a context?

I tried:
Context.getResources().getString(R.string.my_string)

But I can't use is on a non-static method.